# Unable to insert! into lists of various types in Julia (but push! works)

Tags: insert, julia

**UPDATE:** Oops, as pointed out below (very politely) by @rickhg12hs, I simply read the manual wrong. `insert!` totally works.

In Julia, `push!` works for lists of many different types, but `insert!` does not.

For example, consider arrays of type ASCIIString:

```
x = ["a", "b"]
push!(x, "c")
```

results in `x = ["a", "b", "c"]`. But:

```
x = ["a", "b"]
insert!(x, "c", 3)
```

results in:

```
ERROR: `insert!` has no method matching insert!(::Array{ASCIIString,1}, ::ASCIIString, ::Int64)
```

Given this, how can one insert an `ASCIIString` into an arbitrary location in an `Array{ASCIIString, 1}`?

Is the best option simply to re-allocate the entire array? e.g.:

```
x = [x[1:insertIndex-1], itemToInsert, x[insertIndex:end]]
```

Comment: `Base.insert!(collection, index, item)` is the signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insert!` has a different argument order to what you tried.

```
julia> insert! |> methods
# 2 methods for generic function "insert!":
insert!{T}(a::Array{T,1},i::Integer,item) at array.jl:540
insert!(B::BitArray{1},i::Integer,item) at bitarray.jl:595
```

Here is how you can do it.

```
julia> x = ["a", "b"]
2-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "a"
 "b"

julia> insert!(x, 3, "c")
3-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "c"
```

Comment: Yep, you're right. That's a bit embarrassing. Not sure how I stuffed that up. Thanks.